# I can't install mysql on centOS7

Tags: mysql

**I tried to install mysql 5.7 on my CentOS7. However I can't do it..
First I tried following commands**

```
[root@localhost myinstall]# rpm -qa | grep ^mysql-server
[root@localhost myinstall]# yum install mysql-server
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.kakao.com
 * extras: mirror.kakao.com
 * updates: mirror.kakao.com
No package mysql-server available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

**Second, I tried following, but it was also failed..**

```
[root@localhost iwantoinst]# yum -y install http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm                                          | 6.0 kB  00:00:00     
Examining /var/tmp/yum-root-8bl5FQ/mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm: mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch
Marking /var/tmp/yum-root-8bl5FQ/mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-community-release.noarch 0:el7-5 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: mysql57-community-release-fc22-7.noarch conflicts mysql-community-release
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.kakao.com
 * extras: mirror.kakao.com
 * updates: mirror.kakao.com
No package matched to upgrade: mysql-community-release
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: mysql57-community-release conflicts with mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
[root@localhost iwantoinst]# yum -y install mysql-community-server
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.kakao.com
 * extras: mirror.kakao.com
 * updates: mirror.kakao.com
No package mysql-community-server available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

How can I do that? please!

Comment: This is should probably be on Linux/User or SuperUser exchange,

Comment: Boom. Done: https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible for your to use MariaDB instead of MySQL (warning: less than 100% compatibility in edge cases is possible!):

You can download directly from

https://downloads.mariadb.org/

but it is better to use the Repository Configuration Tool at

https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=mva

[image: MariaDB config guide]

So create the file

```
/etc/yum.repos.d/MariaDB.repo
```

with the indicated contents and then

```
yum install MariaDB-server MariaDB-client
```

And then we have this:

```
$ rpm --query --all | grep -i maria

MariaDB-common-10.3.12-1.el7.centos.x86_64
MariaDB-compat-10.3.12-1.el7.centos.x86_64
MariaDB-client-10.3.12-1.el7.centos.x86_64
MariaDB-server-10.3.12-1.el7.centos.x86_64
```

*Running tests*

(I haven't done that yet, shame on me)

Read INSTALL-BINARY

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysqltest/

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysql-test-overview/

Running

```
/home/mysql/mariadb/mysql-test/mtr
```

fails abysmally.

Most of the tests require the debug build!

Comment: Thanks for your favor. I know MariaDB is compatible for MySQL. Even is more popular now. So MySQL is not supported by CentOS? And for me, a beginner of database, is it better to study MariaDB than MySQL

Comment: @남관우 Indeed, CentOS is providing MariaDB packages as replacement for MySQL, but not necessarily the freshest - thus you may want to download from MariaDB website. For MySQL, there are instructions on how to install the required packages: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ and https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/yum/